# House 128 voltsRouter voltage

Tags: power-supply

My house input is 128 volts ,high voltage 
We have a net gear router that has a power supply brick that reads 
100-240 volts, will the power supply absorb the 8 volts and allow my router to work un harmed, as well as my satellite internet receiver and Cisco ata phone box, 
Normally our power is 120volts, however it spikes to 128-129

Comment: 128 volts is a bit outside spec for the grid (as I understand it - maximum should be 126 volts).  In practice this will work though, because the power supplies are switched mode, and will regulate over a wide range of voltages.    Depending on the exact circuitry of the the power supplies it could shorten their lives - but if they truly can handle 100-240 volts its within spec and not a problem.

Comment: Honestly, the router should be the least of your worries... It has a transformer which should step the voltage to tolerable levels for the router. Normal service voltage in the US is 114-126vAC with typical nominal voltages of 117-123vAC. You should consider contacting your electrical provider and report the issue. 128vAC seems a little high. How are you measuring it? Are you using a GOOD voltmeter to check it, like a Fluke/Amprobe/Klien or are you using a $5 Harbor Freight cheapy, because I have seen a 10%+ difference in some cases between a good meter and a cheap/bad/miscalibrated one.

Answer (score 2):

This is an excellent case for a UPS.

What happens during a spike in voltage is that the step-down transformers inside of your devices power-bricks will also spike on the low-voltage side.

I.e if it's supposed to be 110v stepped down to 12v dc, you could see spikes as high as 18 volts. If your devices power bricks are labeled for 240v I would expect them to be able to handle surges up to 24/28vdc on the low-voltage side.

But this is all conjecture not knowing the exact part numbers for your power adapters. To be on the safe side, get a ups. It will switch to battery and inverter during surge periods, giving the device the correct line voltage.

Edit:
Additionally, you should notify your energy supplier. 
They may be able to fix this at the street level, or local distribution level. We have peco here in PA, I had some pretty crazy surges in 2014/2015 that were recorded on the ups in our apartment (at the time a Belkin ups). Peco covered the full cost of a new T.V, and room-mates PC that was affected by it.

But they key here is that we had a record with dates, times and recorded under and over-voltages.

Comment: Except that the power supplies in question are not using step down transformers because they are automatically sensing 120/240 volt nominal - so they are switched mode.

Comment: Lol take one apart, you WILL find a step-down transformer inside. (unless it's a buck or boost style circuit) then it would have the inductor and mosfets in place of the step-down. The difference is usually an iron-core in linear (large heavy) vs a ferrite core in switched-mode power supplies (lighter/small and have good efficiency in high frequency)

Comment: @davidgo If you are interested, check out this link. this includes computer PSU'S btw. I used to take them out of pc power supplies for use in electronics projects. http://www.efxkits.us/switch-mode-power-supply-smps-works/